# Inverse prediction from binomial glm - how to obtain confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, prediction, inverse-prediction

I am trying to use a glm with a binomial distribution (logit link) to analyse data from a dose response curve for the lethal effects of different bacterial strains. I now want to obtain estimates of the lethal dose 50 (LD50).

My model is simply of the form:

```
survival ~ a + b*dose
```

Thus since I have a logit link, obtaining the estimates for the LD50 (i.e. p=0.5) simply means dividing -a/b. However, I am also wanting to know the confidence intervals for these estimates and that's where I am unsure about what to do. If anyone would have a suggestion for this, that would be great.

Comment: Depending on your sample size, you could use bootstrapping to obtain CIs.

Comment: Hi Andrea,

Thanks for your reply. I have 5 datapoints per dose (4 doses). Could you please further explain how the bootstrapping could be done in this case? (sorry, I haven't really used this much).

Cheers,

Ricardo

Comment: Have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423325/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-logistic-regression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package ["drc"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/index.html) for estimation of LD50 and its confidence intervals.

In another way, your glm results can be treated by a simple function "dose.p" in package MASS that calculates LD50 and its SE.